# Strange output from sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have some html files and want to extract only lines with containing these tags:

```
head
p
```

I used sed to extract these parts of the files, as follows:

```
grep "<head>" myfile.html | sed -e 's%\(head\)\(.*\)\(/head\)%title\2\/title%'

grep "<p>" myfile.html | sed -e 's%\(<p>\)\(.*\)\(</p\)\(>\)%\2\\%'
```

Everything is Ok, but I get "\" character at the end of each line. How I can overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use \ at the end of the replacement string:

```
grep "<p>" myfile.html | sed -e 's%\(<p>\)\(.*\)\(</p\)\(>\)%\2%'
```

Answer (score 2):

In this command, you're telling it to add a backslash by including the double backslash:

```
sed -e 's%\(<p>\)\(.*\)\(</p\)\(>\)%\2\\%'
```

Try removing the backslashes:

```
sed -e 's%\(<p>\)\(.*\)\(</p\)\(>\)%\2%'
```

Also, you don't need `grep`:

```
sed -ne '/<p>/{s%\(<p>\)\(.*\)\(</p\)\(>\)%\2%;p}'
```